# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler" using whenever and rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, rake-task, whenever

I am running a rake task using whenever cron job but its giving error **Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":**   code sample is below

*schedule.rb*

```
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}

every 1.minute do
  rake "twitter:search"
end
```

*/lib/tasks/twitter.rake*

```
namespace :twitter do
  desc "Search tweets for user"
  task :search => :environment do

    puts "searching for all users ......."
    # my original code 

  end
end
```

when i run my rake tasks using following commands

```
whenever --update-crontab
crontab -l
```

it run successfully but when i see log file *log/cron_log.log* i got following error after every 1 minute

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.1) depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.0.15)
```

**Note =>** when i run *rake twitter:search* in terminal it run successfully
Thank you for reading post and thanks a lot for suggestion

Comment: Try `bundle exec whenever --update-crontab`

Comment: @dddd1919 error is still same .... thanks for reply

Comment: If have `Gemfile`, run `bundle install ` first

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you have the wrong version of bundler installed.

`rails (= 4.1.1) depends on bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)`

Bundler gem version must be less than `2.0` but greater than or equal to `1.3.0`

`Current Bundler version: bundler (1.0.15)`

The installed version of bundler is `1.0.15` (smaller than `2.0`, but not greater than or equal to `1.3.0`

**TL;DR** install the right version of bundler

`$ gem install bundler --version '<2.0, >= 1.3.0'`

Comment: @Danial i have installed `$ gem install bundler --version '<2.0, >= 1.3.0'` but still got same error when i run my cronjob, its only giving me error inside cronjobs ...

Comment: @HaiderAli if that is the case, then you need to debug your cron ENV to get more information. Try adding a cron script that runs `echo $(which bundler) > ~/bundler_location` and compare that with the output of `echo $(which bundler)` not in cron. You might be using different version of bundler (or maybe rake. You should try that too)

Comment: Got a new error using the "echo" task.  >> rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError).  This to spite being able to get the version, update bunder, etc without error in the console.  Switching gems now to something with working instructions.